# Why does a hash table formatting change automatically?

Tags: powershell, formatting, hashtable, powershell-4.0

I want to know why removing the comment tag from the 'NextRun' property in the hash table in the below code causes the default formatting to switch from table to list.

```
$a=Get-ScheduledTask|sort state`
$b=$a|Get-ScheduledTaskInfo`

for ($i=0; $i -lt $a.Count;$i+=1)`

    {$props=@{'Name'       =$a[$i].TaskName;
              'Description'=$a[$i].description;
              'State'      =$a[$i].state;
             #'NextRun'    =$b[$i].nextruntime;
              'LastRun'    =$b[$i].lastruntime}
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSOBject -Property $props
$obj}`
```

Or, is there a different object type that will prevent it from happening ?

Comment: The default formatting of the hashtable doesnt change, what changes is the formatting of the PSObject. Still no clue why it changes the formatting since the only difference between those objects is the NextRun Property.
You can circumvent this by piping to ft though

Comment: Not really. `$obj|ft` causes the column headers to appear multiple times.

Comment: ok next workaround: create `$objArr=@()`, replace `$obj` with `$objArr +=$obj` and output `$objArr | ft` after the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When outputting object properties without a formatting cmdlet, PowerShell looks at the number of properties to determine if it's going to use a table or list. In my experience, five or more properties auto-format to a list, where any less auto-format to a table.

In this case you would need to use a formatting cmdlet to affect the output formatting, or output less properties to change the auto-formatting.

Comment: But `$obj|ft` causes the column headers to appear multiple times.

Comment: That's because every time you call `ft`, it outputs a new table. You can collect all of the objects generated and format the output of the collection. @Paul has an example in the comments above using an array.